# Magento 2.2: Add/Remove class in a div from default.xml

Tags: xml, magento2.2

How to add or remove a class in the store-switcher div from default.xml ?

I tried this :

```
   <referenceBlock name="store_switcher">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">switcher-store</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my_new_class</argument>
       </arguments>
   </referenceBlock>
```

And this :

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlId="switcher-store" htmlClass="my_new_class"/>
```

(I moved the store_switcher block to the header-wrapper container)

But none works.

Comment: 2.2 removes the ability to do this... I'm not sure what the solution is now though

Comment: any news about that ?